# How do you modify or delete a directory that was previously an EFS access point?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-efs

I have an EFS drive on AWS.

I create an access point mounted at `/access`.

Delete the access point after it has mounted oncee.

The directory `access` is still in the root of the EFS drive with the same permissions.

I try running `rm -rf access` and `chown -R 1000:1000 access` but both give me permission denied whether I am running root, user 1000 or a new user with the id that matches the access point.

How can I modify or delete this directory that was previously an EFS access point?